# To sum the columns and display results in other column

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, data-manipulation

This is bugging me from 2days.

I have data like

```
   Account.ID asset_name
      6yS        A
      6yS        B
      6yS        B
      6yS        C
      6yU        D
      876        C
```

From here I want to make more columns of like dummies. But I want only one row each ID.

My output should look like this

```
   Account.ID asset_name  Flag_A  Flag_B  Flag_C  Flag_D
     6yS          A           1      2      1       0     
     6yU          D           0      0      0       1
     876          C           0      0      1       0
```

I tried aggregating but they make it into another table, which I do not want to merge again, because I will be losing information.

Please help me out. 
Thank y'll in advance.

Comment: In result, there dont need to asset_name. Please excuse my mistake. Thank you

Comment: in result we dont need to have asset_name. The data im working had asset name and account id. I removed the details of account id, which is large id numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have an answer for you. So this is your dataset:

```
Account.ID <- c("6yS", "6yS", "6yS", "6yS", "6yU", 876)
asset_name <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "C")

df <- data.frame(Account.ID, asset_name)
df

  Account.ID asset_name
1        6yS          A
2        6yS          B
3        6yS          B
4        6yS          C
5        6yU          D
6        876          C
```

For further transformations I am using tidyverse, so install it and load the library:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

df <-df %>% 
  group_by(Account.ID, asset_name) %>%
  summarize(n=n()) %>%
  spread(asset_name, n)
df

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Account.ID [3]
  Account.ID     A     B     C     D
  <fct>      <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 6yS            1     2     1    NA
2 6yU           NA    NA    NA     1
3 876           NA    NA     1    NA
```

Now all that needs to be done is turn NAs into 0 and rename columns:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0

names(df)[2:ncol(df)] <- paste0("Flag_", names(df)[2:ncol(df)]) 
df

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Account.ID [3]
  Account.ID Flag_A Flag_B Flag_C Flag_D
  <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 6yS             1      2      1      0
2 6yU             0      0      0      1
3 876             0      0      1      0
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @praveenbushipaka if you find this method working, please mark this answer as a solution

Answer (score 3):

This one?

```
 df %>% 
   count(Account.ID, asset_name) %>% 
   tidyr::pivot_wider( names_from =  asset_name, 
                       values_from = n,
                       values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Account.ID     A     B     C     D
  <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 6yS            1     2     1     0
2 6yU            0     0     0     1
3 876            0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dcast` from `data.table` with `fun.aggregate` argument:

```
library(data.table)

dcast(data = setDT(df)[, asset_name := paste0('Flag_', asset_name)], 
      formula = Account.ID ~ asset_name, 
      fun.aggregate = length)
```

Output:

```
   Account.ID Flag_A Flag_B Flag_C Flag_D
1:        6yS      1      2      1      0
2:        6yU      0      0      0      1
3:        876      0      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution, although not the most elegant.

```
Account.ID <- c('6yS', '6yS', '6yS', '6yS', '6yU', '876')
asset_name <- c('A','B','B','C','D','C')
df <- data.frame(Account.ID, asset_name)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Account.ID, asset_name) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  spread(key = asset_name, value = Count, fill = 0)
```

Returns:

```
  Account.ID     A     B     C     D
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 6yS            1     2     1     0
2 6yU            0     0     0     1
3 876            0     0     1     0
```